# Building a table from a text file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a table from a text file, however:
When I compile the program the information entered appears followed by the table it's supposed to appear in, but the table is blank. Clearly I'm making a mistake somewhere.. can you help?

```
   StreamReader swreNames = File.OpenText("Names.txt");

        do
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 2);
            Console.Write("--- Names Table ---");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 4);
            Console.Write("First Name");
            swrNames.WriteLine(firstname); // Reads from first name from file Names.txt
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, Counter + 6); // Aligns first name within table settings 
            Console.SetCursorPosition(28, 4);
            Console.Write("Surname");
            swrNames.WriteLine(lastname); // Reads from last name from file Names.txt
            Console.SetCursorPosition(28, Counter + 6);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(48, 4);
            Console.Write("Age");
            swrNames.WriteLine(age); // Reads from age from file Names.txt
            Console.SetCursorPosition(48, Counter + 6);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        } while ((firstname = swreNames.ReadLine()) != null); //Writes out the input from the text file
```

OK I've edited the code to show where I think there is a problem, hopefully it's in slightly easier reading format!

Please help.

Comment: Ok, you've shared _all_ of your code, now can you indicate where there is a problem?  When you step through in a debugger, at what point does the observed behavior deviate from the expected behavior?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: Now please refactor your code so all functions are 5-7 lines long and than keep *only one* in the sample posted here (the one that causes problem). Also try to avoid that many empty lines in the post.

Comment: this is my issue, there are no errors - when I run the program everything runs as it should (at least on the face of it) yet the data should appear in the table but it just appears prior to the table being displayed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, i'm not that advanced as yet... could anyone help me please?

Comment: I've edited the post now hopefully this will make more sense.

Comment: @BazH Try changing your code to something like: `string currentLine = swreNames.ReadLine(); while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLine){... currentLine = swreNames.ReadLine();}`

Comment: BTW, you should move your title row to outside the loop, otherwise you'll end up having a title row for each content row.

Comment: Could you post you file content?

Comment: @AndreCalil Hi Andre, the file content is just what I'm making up at the momentm I can post the whole program if it will help you help me?!

Comment: @BazH Yes I will, but I must know how your data is stored in your file. Could you copy&paste the file content?

Comment: Barry
Horton
33
Barry
Horton
33
Barry
Horton
33
Barry 
Horton
33
Barry
Horton
33

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter too early, this is how the data appears in the names.txt file. and in turn is how it appears on screen in the program.

Comment: If I had the file structure I could write you something real quick but for some reason OP's never seem to post the important pieces of code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, **let's suppose** that your file's content follow the format `[first name] [last name]`, like:

```
Axl Rose
Joey Ramone
Steve Vai
BB King
```

So, your code would look like:

```
        StreamReader fileContent = File.OpenText(@"C:\my-file.txt");

        Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 2);
        Console.Write("--- Names Table ---");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 4);
        Console.Write("First Name");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(28, 4);
        Console.Write("Surname");

        int topOffset = 6;

        string currentLine = fileContent.ReadLine();

        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentLine))
        {
            string firstName = currentLine.Split(' ')[0];
            string lastName = currentLine.Split(' ')[1];

            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, topOffset);
            Console.Write(firstName);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(28, topOffset);
            Console.Write(lastName);

            topOffset += 2;
            currentLine = fileContent.ReadLine();
        }

        fileContent.Dispose();

        Console.ReadLine();
```

This is **not** the best solution and your file might differ from this format. Well, now it's your turn to write code.

Comment: BB King made me laugh! Thank you - BB and Axl in the same band !

Comment: Well, that's not a _band_ file, but you got it. Please, give a try and provide any feedback you have.

Comment: @BazH Nothing so far? Don't forget to mark it as correct if it's what you were looking for

Comment: sorry had to pop out this evening, I'm starting now should update you shortly :)

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from the file stream when your comments say you are writing, and writing when your comments say you are reading. You never put the data you read into the console stream.

Also you are putting the entire read line of the file stream, one at a time into file name and writing that back to the same stream... not really advisable there.

Comment: all, I'm quite literally learning I'm something like week 6 into c# so pardon me for not being upto your levels. i thought this would be a good idea. yet its not i'm sure you all recall this stage in your programming life. when everything made sense on the board then you get home and its all gone from the brain!  i'll seek assistance from lecturer rather than here, prob less embarrassing than